# Not able to connect to prosysopcua over https connection

Tags: python, ssl, https, opc-ua, opc

So there are 2 type of endpoints to connect to opcua simulation server, one is tcp and the other is https.
[image]

i tried everything i can to connect for the https endpoint, but i am getting no luck.

this is my python code:

```
    `host, port = address.split("/")[2].split(":")
    server_address = host
    server_port = int(port)
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
    ssl_context.check_hostname = False
    ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    ssl_socket = ssl_context.wrap_socket(client_socket, server_hostname=server_address)
    ssl_socket.connect((server_address, server_port))
    node_id = "ns=3;i=1002"  # Replace with your desired NodeId
    message = (
            b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00'
            b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'
            b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00' + len(node_id).to_bytes(4, byteorder='little')
            + node_id.encode()
    )
    content_type = b'application/octet-stream'
    request = (
            b"POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            b"Host: " + server_address.encode() + b"\r\n"
            b"Content-Type: " + content_type + b"\r\n"
            b"Content-Length: " + str(
        len(message)).encode() + b"\r\n"
                                      b"\r\n" + message
    )
    ssl_socket.send(request)
    response = ssl_socket.recv(4096)
    print("Response:\n", response)
    ssl_socket.close()`
```

for the above code this is the error i receive:

`Response:  b'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nDate: Wed, 05 Jul 2023 06:03:07 GMT\r\nContent-Length: 75\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n\x00\x00\x00\x00S\x80A\x00\x00\x00Bad_EndOfStream (code=0x80B00000, description="Buffer underflow")'`

I need to get the values of objects using object id. the protocol has to be htpps.

Answer (score 0):

The http protocol for opc ua is realy complex. You have to implement a lot of specs, like the encoding layer, security features and so on. .

I would just use the normal opc ua tcp with a [asyncua](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio).

If you realy need to use https, you could at least use the asyncua binary encoding and datatypes to help, generate the correct binary messages.

Comment: Is there a documentation where I can refer to generate proper binary messages

Comment: There is no example in https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/master/asyncua/ua/ua_binary.py the encoding is provided. In https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/tree/master/asyncua/ua all structs are provided. See https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part6/v104/docs/7.4.4#_Ref468675554 for how to send messages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your message is here, but you need to be aware that your client needs to communicate OPC UA binary messages over HTTPS.

So, you will not be able to make it with a simple HTTP client - you will need to use an OPC UA client that can open a proper OPC UA client-server session over HTTPS using OPC UA service calls encoded as UA Binary messages.

This is confusing and we (Prosys OPC) don't usually recommend the UA HTTPS unless you have no option to use UA TCP.